# With jQuery, how do i detect if an element is 'mouseovered' and any child elements of that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning, mouseover

Here is what I have so far:

```
var hoveredElement; //none per default

;(function($){
$.fn.isHovered = function(){
    return (hoveredElement.length && $( this )[0] === hoveredElement[0] );
};

})(jQuery);


$(document).mouseover( function(e){
    hoveredElement = $(e.target);
});


$(document).mouseover( function(e){
    console.log( $(this).isHovered() );
});
```

Basically I have the following structure:

```
<div id='one'>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
            three
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I mouse over two, i'd like to return true whether it is #two or #three that I am mousing over.

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.hover()` API: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ and you should be able to view the current object via `$(this)`.

Something like:

```
$('div').hover( 
function() { console.log('hovering over %o', $(this) }, 
function() { console.log('leaving') }
);
```

Comment: That isnt really what I want. I need a function that returns a bool whether the element or its children are hovered.

Comment: Like I said, I am not performing an action on hover, but rather altering flow of another script depending on whether or not that item is hovered.

Comment: I managed to create a afunction that sets a variable using this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into **[mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**, and **[mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)** it should give you what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LjUu7/2/